# How to edit transformer as javascript script in Mirth (rather then as individual steps)?

Tags: mirth

How to edit transformer as javascript script in Mirth (3.10) (rather then as individual Mapper steps constrained by the building block UI)? I can see that the primary UI for each step is generating JS code and I'd like to play with that code directly (eg. have a single script that composites all of the JS Transformer logic). (Am totally new to using Mirth)

Eg. I want to set output message values as more complex values than those that can fit in a a single line of javascript available in the primary Transformer UI and be able to organize steps beyond continually clicking the "move step up/down" menu button.

The only thing I've seen so far as managing the Source Transformer on a more controlled level is exporting the XML (I'm assuming this is not how people are meant to interact/edit with the transformers).

I see the scripts tab in the main Channel UI, but IDK how to make that "connect" / act for the Source Transformer (scanned over the [user manual](https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-310-user-guide.pdf), but was not able to figure this out yet).

Anyone with more experience know how to do this? Any links that could explain / show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a transformer, you can add a new step (right click in a blank space or with the menu in the left bar), then you can change the type of the new line to "JavaScript"
([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH0IY.png))

Then, the space in the bottom changes to a blank page where you can type your JavaScript code.